# Scala: pattern match problem with fully qualified classnames in parameterization

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a little problem in pattern matching an object in Scala when it is parameterized with a fully qualified class name. This is based on Scala 2.9.0.1. Anyone knows what's wrong with this code?

```
scala> "foo" match {
 | case y : Seq[Integer] =>
 | case y : Seq[java.lang.Integer] =>
<console>:3: error: ']' expected but '.' found.
   case y : Seq[java.lang.Integer] =>
```

Why does the first version work, but the latter fail? The problem only seems to occur when a fully qualified classname is used for the parameterization.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), section 8.1 Patterns, the identifier after the : needs to be what is referred to as a Type Pattern, defined in Section 8.2:

> Type patterns consist of types, type variables, and wildcards. A type
>   pattern T is of one of the following forms:
>
> ...
>
> A parameterized type pattern T [a(1), . . . , a(n)], where the a(i) are
>   type variable patterns or wildcards _. This type pattern matches all
>   values which match T for some arbitrary instantiation of the type
>   variables and wildcards. The bounds or alias type of these type
>   variable are determined as described in (§8.3).
>
> ...
>
> A type variable pattern is a simple identifier which starts with a
>   lower case letter. However, the predefined primitive type aliases
>   unit, boolean, byte, short, char, int, long, float, and double are not
>   classified as type variable patterns.

So, syntactically, you can't use a fully qualified class as a type variable pattern IN THIS POSITION. You can however, use a type alias, so:

```
type JavaInt = java.lang.Integer
List(new java.lang.Integer(5)) match {
    case y: Seq[JavaInt] => 6
    case _ => 7
}
```

will return 6 as expected. The problem is that as Alan Burlison points out, the following also returns 6:

```
List("foobar") match {
    case y: Seq[JavaInt] => 6
    case _ => 7
}
```

because the type is being erased. You can see this by running the REPL, or scalac with the -unchecked option.

Comment: Wow. I hit this today and eventually found this question. I had no idea such a thing as a "type variable pattern" even existed in Scala. What else is still hiding from me in the SLS...?

Comment: Some of the easter eggs only activate on 1/4 and Easter.

Comment: I started a thread on this at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-language/2PNDjkI47Ao/MCQw7RzNUwcJ

Comment: and there is now a ticket at https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7985 ; Martin Odersky says it's a parser bug

Answer (score 3):

In fact your first example doesn't work either.  If you run the REPL with -unchecked, you'll see the following error:

> warning: non variable type-argument Integer in type pattern Seq[Integer] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

So you can't actually do what you are trying to do - at run-time there's no difference between a List[Integer] and a List[AnythingElse], so you can't pattern-match on it.  You might be able to do this with a Manifest, see http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/ScalasTypeSystem.html#Manifests and http://www.scala-blogs.org/2008/10/manifests-reified-types.html

Comment: I don't think type erasure was the point of the question. How about this:    `"foo".asInstanceOf[Any] match {` <br/>
   `case x: Seq[Integer] => ` <br/> `case y: Seq[java.lang.Integer] => `<br/> `} `

Comment: @Jamil, I believe `Seq[java.lang.Integer]` is just a syntax error.  I believe the compiler is treating `java.lang.Integer` as an identifier and they can't have dots in them.  You can demonstrate this by surrounding `java.lang.Integer` in backquotes - it will then compile but you'll still get the same erasure warning that you do with plain `Integer`.  I agree the error is misleading, but it's not all that surprising considering that you can't really do what @Frank is trying to do anyway.

Comment: `java.lang.Integer` is a type not a variable. Moreover Scala binds to variable when you use Constructor pattern, or tuple or sequence etc. Oddly enough, if I use the alias  `type myint = java.lang.Integer` Scala doesn't complain

Comment: @Jamil, I know it's a type, that's the whole point - the compiler is expecting a variable and tries to interpret `java.lang.Integer` as one, but it's not a valid variable name as it has dots in it.